# Cutting Irregular Shape into an Irregular Cylinder (plane cockpit)

Tags: modeling

I've been battling with a problem for a few days, which i'm unable to resolve without creating awful topology/triangles etc. I've tried the Boolean route, but when it came to using subdiv surface / edge looping, the results were terrible due to all the triangles etc...

I've gone back to the drawing board to try and create a cleaner version, but i'm unable to figure out how to cut a cockpit (red line - see image) into the plane fuselage.  I tried subdividing into smaller squares then inset > pulling the cockpit quads down.  But this resulted in loads of triangular teeth around the edges.

Any suggestions on how to cut but retain good topology would be much appreciated!

[image: Cut required]

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cockpit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So why don't you simply cut this part with a knife? Plus before adding edge loops you should make sure that the whole shape is good.

[image]

Some steps :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this... I'm pretty new to blender so it took me a while to try and figure out how you jumped from your second screenie to the more complete third. Unsure if its correct https://imgur.com/a/aAoHzeH

My concern is that when i add a new loop cut (see image). It just ends at the hole and doesn't carry on the other side.  Doesn't this create topology issues further down the proces (UV Unwrap etc)?  How would i go about redirecting the cut around the hole?

Comment: yes except you should work with less edges around the cylinder, only add edges if necessary, some of your edges, the horizontal ones all around the cylinder, are useless, at least for the moment, you can test it, if you delete them and it doesn't change the whole shape it meant they were not useful

Comment: I think you may have missed the edits on my previous message :) sorry.  So I dont need any new horizontal edge loop to be linked both sides of the hole? I will also cull come of my lines.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can dissolve at least one out of 2 of these horizontal edges: https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/ypi5.jpg   the simpler your shape is the better it will be, then only add edges if necessary. Try first to model a vary basic shape with as few edges as possible, with all your plane elements: cockpit, wings, etc... work from the biggest to the smallest

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate the time you've spent on this - there's a lot to take in when beginning 3D! Just one more question before I mark as answered.  How did you create this red line https://imgur.com/a/Lzy1nKF?  I extruded > right click > scale and dragged in.  But there must be a cleaner method?

Comment: The red line is actually my original knife cut, but the display is a bit misleading, please look at my answer's edit, I explain step by step

Comment: Great, thanks Moonboots.  This is my attempt using my limited skills.  Ive simplified the general mesh a bit and added loops to the edges of the hole to sharpen them.  I also clicked the 'on cage' button inside the subsurf modifier.  Doesnt look too bad :) https://imgur.com/a/7089rzl

Comment: I only clicked on the cage option for fun and for aesthetic  ;)  don't use it when you model your object. Ok good luck!

Comment: +1 for a very pretty aeroplane. Nice to see you back :)

Comment: thanks, nice to see you too   ;)